# Getting a smart contract, web3 python

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3py

How can I access smart contract calls with only the address of the contract? Correctly, I understand that the address will be enough, because with the help of it I can refer to the contract date field, and by decoding the abi?

It is also not clear why in web3, when referring to a contract, it is obligatory to use both the address and abi?

```
token_contract = w3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi)
```

why not:

```
token_contract = w3.eth.contract(address=address)
```

Comment: Abi provides high level interface to interact with contract by calling the object methods. Abi is not stored on blockchain so you should provide it to create a contract abstraction. Without it you can use raw calls encoding call and parameters yourself. There is web3.eth.abi module for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Abi tells how to interact with/use your contract. Address alone is not enough, it just points to contract on blockchain which is stored in binary form(opcodes). Abi is like an user manual of smart contract.

Comment: Your answer provides insight. You may add some custom working code to your answer in order turn it into an actual solution. Insights and commets like this are most welcome but is more common practice to place it inside comments regarding the author's question.

Answer (score 2):

> The ABI encodes information about smart contracts' functions and
> events. It acts as an interface between EVM-level bytecode and
> high-level smart contract program code. To interact with a smart
> contract deployed on the Ethereum blockchain, external programs
> require an ABI and the address of the smart contract.